# loading UIViewController faster

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, loading

i have six viewControllers and six buttons in my project. every button brings the appropriate ViewController. but the thing is when the user taps for example 4th button then the application freze for one or two seconds and then the requested ViewControl is loaded. all i want to do is to make that things faster. i mean i checked some applications there it was done like first the requested ViewController is brought then it starts to load the controls. how i can do such thing in my application ?

Comment: 1)Post some code, so we can see,how you release etc, 2) Are you using 1 xib for each ViewController? Or are you creating them programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "Time Profiler" tool in instruments you can see which functions in your code are slow. This should help figure out where your code is slowing down.

For instance, if you swapped all your view controllers out with blank ones you shouldn't see any freezing. Chances are something in your view controller initialization code is slowing you down.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i just push the new view like that
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CollectionsView" sender:self];
and in that CollectionsCiew's viewDidLoad method i parse a source and i think that makes it slow. but where else i can parse the source ?

Comment: If a generic method like viewDidLoad is running slow then a good idea is to break down your code. If you are doing 10 different things in your viewDidLoad method, split each one up into it's own method. This way the time profiler will be more specific. It can also make your code easier to read :)